# Attach Shopware 6 tags to Property values

Tags: php, vue.js, shopware, shopware6

Can someone advice on making it possible to attach Shopware 6 tags to Property (only one) values?

Is there a way to reuse some components? I assume tags are done using data associations.

--

I have set it up, but now I get this error (while not being able to open Property option detail modal on click in a backend administration options list):

```
app.js?16886789168584353:2 An error was captured in current module: ReferenceError: option is not defined
```

It opens well, when I remove the selector:

```
    <sw-entity-tag-select
        v-if="option"
        v-model="option.extensions.myTags"
        :label="$tc('global.sw-tag-field.title')"
    />
```

Here is the js:

```
Shopware.Component.override('sw-property-option-detail', {
    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    template,

    data: function () {
        return {
            option: undefined
        }
    },

    computed: {
        repository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('a7filter_property_group_option_tag');
        },
        criteria() {
            const criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.addAssociation('myTags');

            return criteria;
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.repository = this.repositoryFactory.create('a7filter_property_group_option_tag');

        this.repository.search(this.criteria, Shopware.Context.api)
            .then(option => {
                this.option = option;
            });
    }
});
```

Maybe someone can give an advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [custom entity](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-entities) for the mapping

```php
class MyPropertyGroupOptionTagDefinition extends MappingEntityDefinition
{
    final public const ENTITY_NAME = 'my_property_group_option_tag';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new FkField('option_id', 'optionId', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('tag_id', 'tagId', TagDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('option', 'option_id', PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class, 'id', false),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('tag', 'tag_id', TagDefinition::class, 'id', false),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Create an [`EntityExtension`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities)

```php
class PropertyGroupOptionExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new ManyToManyAssociationField('myTags', TagDefinition::class, MyPropertyGroupOptionTagDefinition::class, 'option_id', 'tag_id'),
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PropertyGroupOptionDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Add association to criteria for `property_group_option` where they are fetched

```js
criteria.addAssociation('myTags');
```

In the template of the component you can use `sw-entity-tag-select` for assigning tags

```html
<sw-entity-tag-select
    v-if="option"
    v-model="option.extensions.myTags"
    :label="$tc('global.sw-tag-field.title')"
/>
```

Comment: I have set it up, but now I get this error (while not being able to open Property option detail modal on click in a backend administration options list) - please check the code in the question above

Comment: Still trying to make it work getting 'ReferenceError: dump is not defined', 'api/search/a7filter-property-group-option-tag 500' and 'response: "{\"errors\":[{\"status\":\"500\",\"code\":\"FRAMEWORK__ASSOCIATION_NOT_FOUND\",\"title\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"detail\":\"Can not find association by name myTags\",\"' errors. Should Permissions be setup for this? https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-entities#permissions